# Area optimization: Packing rectangles inside rectangle

Tags: calculus, matrices, graph-theory, optimization, image-processing

#### Background:

I am scrambling to figure out the optimization algorithm to build [sprite image](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites), which is essentially a big container rectangular image, with multiple rectangular images.

I have found an elaborated [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu#place) to solve this problem. But to incorporate more parameters to the mix requires good grasp on mathematical aspect of the solution. Bottom line; I am interested in mathematical solution of this problem (perhaps with scary equations).

---

#### The Problem:

Algorithm: Given multiple rectangular images, with uneven dimensions; width and heights (in pixel). Our goal is to merge all the images on an empty transparent canvas *without overlapping*.

Mathematics: Find the `(x, y)` start-point coordinate of each rectangle, where to begin drawing on the resultant rectangle (canvas); the final *sprite image*.

The parameters:

- Collections of images to merge: with meta information, viz; Height, Width, Resolution etc.
- Aspect ratio to maintain for sprite image.

  - Default value: `any` (that is; enumeration for [one's complement
    ~0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/387429/863980)); flexible for the
    most optimized results.
  - Could be a x-y pair: `4:3`, `6:3` etc.
- Gutter size (default -> 1 pixel): spacing between adjacent images and edges of the sprite.

---

#### Questions:

- Which domain is most suitable to solve this problem: Matrix, Calculus or Graph Theory?
- What area optimization techniques would entertain the parameters like *desired aspect ratio* (as mentioned previously its an optional parameter, defaulted to `any`)?
- Can it be solved with Calculus' differentiation (perhaps using [Newton Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method))?

Comment: This is, in general, a combinatorial optimization problem. Therefore, with no additional constraints between the objects, most algorithms will aim to heuristically find an approximate solution.

Comment: @vulcan raven You might try thinking of this as a tiling problem.